# map current location in fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, currentlocation

We are getting the code in activity.But not able to implement in fragment.Here is the code in activity.Please help us to find the current location in fragment.
We are able to put markers in fragment but we are not able to get the current location in fragment.Please help us as we are doing an application dealing with maps.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Delivered")
            .position(new LatLng(10.01, 76.34)));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Delivered")
            .position(new LatLng(9.99, 76.31)));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Delivered")
            .position(new LatLng(9.99, 76.30)));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Delivered")
            .position(new LatLng(10.52, 76.21)));
    markerPoints.add(new LatLng(10.01, 76.34));
    markerPoints.add(new LatLng(9.99, 76.31));
    markerPoints.add(new LatLng(9.99, 76.30));
    markerPoints.add(new LatLng(10.52, 76.21));
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            mMap.clear();
            markerPoints.clear();
        }
    });
}
private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String waypoints = "";
    for(int i=2;i<markerPoints.size();i++){
        LatLng point  = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(i);
        if(i==2)
            waypoints = "waypoints=";
        waypoints += point.latitude + "," + point.longitude + "|";
    }
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+waypoints;
    String output = "json";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;
    return url;
}
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String data = "";
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        }
        mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);}
        return false;} else {
        return true;
    }}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();}
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);}
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;}}}}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  describe in more details with code

Comment: we are  trying to get current location in fragment.we are getting in activity but not able to integrate in fragment

Comment: OK so what's the problem you're facing in fragment ?

Comment: google map is just displayed without current location

Comment: ok So where is your code ? You developed something,  Did you ?

Comment: Above is the code in activity.We are not able to do it in fragment.

Comment: Can you please help us with code to get current location in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter if you are in fragment or not. You should get the current location like any other way e.g using [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)

Comment: But how to implement with  FusedLocationProviderApi,can you please  provide with the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch your location from your activity and once you will get the location you will send it to your fragment.
But If you are looking for Location API sample then look at it.
Click [Sample](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/)

I hope it will work for you.
Good Luck!!